# Buildbox Apk Generation in Eclipse Or Android Studio gives same logcat error

Tags: java, c++

When i try to build apk (a project from Buildbox) in Eclipse or Android studio then it gives same logcat error and due to this when i try to install the generated apk in my phone it gives a message that app not working.

And the Error message it shows is:
**Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8c in tid 10752(GL Thread 2531)** as Text and libc as Tag.

Please help me to carry Out this problem!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to access an array and you're out of bounds. Double check and make sure your arrays are all allocated and accessed properly

Comment: Using libraries and functions that aren't thread safe can also trigger that. Check those too